# Downloading maptile: /0/0/0 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, eclipse, openstreetmap, android-virtual-device, osmdroid

Yesterday, I made my first Android-OpenStreetMap application with Eclipse and the AVD Emulator. I used Osmdroid library and everything worked fine. Map was show. The application was the most simple one, I just made what many tutorials recomend. Very very simple application. And it worked fine.

Everything is OK: manifest, permissions, .java code, libraries, everything.

But today, the exactly same code (I just turned on Eclipse and executed the app) does not work. Map is empty. No maps.

I have installed again eclipse, change debug key, try app on a mobile device, change example, many many things... But it doesn't work. Map is not show. And the code is exactly the same as yesterday.

In logCat I read this:

Problem downloading maptile: /0/0/0 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Could it be the problem ??? The app is very very simple and I just proved it for 2 minutes.

I don't know what to do and I have to present the project in 5 days. Please, help.

Thanks very much

Comment: If you change the tile source to MAPQUESTOSM, it will work again. It seems Mapnik is blocked for some reason.

Comment: @NickT That's just a workaround. The correct solution is to set a valid user-agent as required by the [tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy).

Comment: @NickT as of july 11 2016 the MAPQUESTOSM has no more . its better to set the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with user-agent, update your osmdroid-android project and it should be fine. For more informations, check this: https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=515